# Is it safe to use the Android Application Context for the various methods in Xamain.Auth

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.auth

Xamrin.Auth (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth), when used on Android, requires any method that accesses the account store to pass a `Context` to the call.

I am wondering if it's ok you always use the Application Context via    `getApplicationContext()`

My use case is initializing an IOC at application startup and passing that context to my lib which manages Xamarin.Auth calls.

I am either missing it or the Xamarin.Auth docs don't say which context is appropriate to use: Application vs Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not always okay to use the application context as **each context has a different "lifecycle" it's tied to**. Wrong usage of `Context` can result in major memory leaks in your application.

In the case of initializing a library, you should always use the application context as it will span the lifecycle of the application.

However if you only need the context for the lifespan of an object in a `Activity`, then you should use the `Activity`'s context.

Comment: Since my service container/registry is initialized in the Application's OnCreate() (not in the Activity) It probably makes the most sense then to use the `ApplicationContext` I am going to assume based on your information above.

Comment: That would be a good assumption. My rule of thumb is typically "Use the `Context` within the scope of where you're initializing". For example, if you needed a `Context` when initializing in the `Activity`, you would use the `Activity` `Context`.